# Force LINQ to SQL or ENTITIES to emit BETWEEN operator

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework

When dealing with SQL Server and dates that are clustered indexes, in order to properly access the index the query must be in the form of:

```
select fields
  from dbo.MyTable
 where myDate between @begDate and @endDate
```

The between operator is what triggers the clustered seek.  How can I tell LINQ to emit the between operator instead of >= this and <= that?

Comment: Have you seen different query plans for BETWEEN and >=/<=?

Comment: Not necessarily different plans.  What ends up happening is called parameter sniffing.

Comment: It might not be a part of EF. [But this article might help you implement it yourself](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/How-to-implement-the-49d3ff40). Alternately, for queries that need to be optimized you might consider not using EF at all - use a stored procedure, [Dapper.Net](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net), or just plain raw ADO.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer, i'd suggest to post it as an answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Linq does not have a between operator or equivalent.  The best (and possibly) only way to achieve this is in sql.

If you are looking to write complex or optimized queries, it is better to use sql rather than linq.  The main advantages for this are:

- Code can be fully tested in management studio, without having to translate and debug in a second language
- For legacy purposes, it is generally better to use sql for database access code, as this is more widely known amongst database experts.  LINQ is the curse of DBAs who have to manage/support code written by others.

I agree with Gerge Mauer's suggestion to use a stored procedure or ADO.

This might still leave you with the problem of parameter sniffing, in which case you may have to use query hints such as OPTIMIZE FOR / RECOMPILE, or local variables to get around this, as demonstrated in this article:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/turgays/archive/2013/09/10/parameter-sniffing-problem-and-workarounds.aspx

Comment: Worth noting is that you can plug a stored procedure to the ORM and still use other benefits ORMs provide like materializing entities, enabling lazy loading on those entities, change tracking, etc.

Comment: I disagree with using sql for database code. This is a really old debate and I'm sure you know all the arguments but, as a full-stack developer I actively discourage DBAs from getting their grubby hands on my application database. It's part of the application, nobody and nothing should be in there. Modifying it out-of-band is similar to unsafe rewriting of parts of memory. That being said, sql absolutely has a place and this is as reasonable one as any. Also Dapper.Net is great for this sort of thing.